IOException parsing XML document from class path resource (in my case Java spring with maven project and using jdk-21 )
On project derectory open this folder "target" --> "classes" in this folder sowing projects package and in package stored .class files
I open my project in file explorer and copy my "configuration/applicationCotext.xml" folder (configuration is package) and paste In "classes" and run my main.java file it is run successfully! 
See this image for better understanding...
Java spring (with maven) project derectory
IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
Showing this error Than use full

The file you have highlighted is a configuration file.  Do you want to parse the configuration?

If you use maven the file configuration/applicationCotext.xmlshould be inside main/resourses and not main/java!
